# Default location in map-kit in ios

Tags: ios, mapkit, mapkitannotation

I am new to IOS i need to show default location with my latitude and longitude(12.940358, 80.208647).
with annotation pin.

.h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
@interface Map_view : UIViewController<MKMapViewDelegate,CLLocationManagerDelegate>{
    CLLocationManager *locationmgr;
    CLGeocoder *geocode;
    CLPlacemark *placemark;

}
@property(nonatomic,retain)IBOutlet MKMapView *map11;
```

.m file:

```
@synthesize map11;
```

I don't no where to put my latitude and longitude and how to use please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to show your location with your lat & long with Annotation With Name.

Use this code.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    mapVW.showsUserLocation = YES;
    CLLocation *loc = [[CLLocation alloc]initWithLatitude:12.940358 longitude:80.208647];

    [mapVW setCenterCoordinate:loc.coordinate animated:YES];

    CLGeocoder *ceo = [[CLGeocoder alloc]init];
    [ceo reverseGeocodeLocation:loc
              completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
                  CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];

                  //String to hold address
                 NSString *locatedAt = [[placemark.addressDictionary valueForKey:@"FormattedAddressLines"] componentsJoinedByString:@", "];
                 NSString *cityName = placemark.locality;

                  MKPointAnnotation *annotationPoint = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
                  annotationPoint.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(12.940358, 80.208647);
                  annotationPoint.title = locatedAt;

                  MKCoordinateRegion region;

                  MKCoordinateSpan span1;
                  span1.latitudeDelta =  0.08;
                  span1.longitudeDelta = 0.08;
                  region.span = span1;
                  region.center = annotationPoint.coordinate;
                  [mapVW setRegion:region animated:TRUE];
                  [mapVW regionThatFits:region];

                  [mapVW addAnnotation:annotationPoint];
                  [mapVW selectAnnotation:annotationPoint animated:NO];
              }
     ];

}
```

Comment: if two latitude and longitude means @Kuldeep

Answer (score 0):

For centering on user location, you can use the following code:

```
[mapView setCenterCoordinate:mapView.userLocation.location.coordinate animated:YES];
```

For zooming on special locations, you should study how the regions (MKCoordinateRegion) are counted and work, count your latitude and longitude values for the region and display it using call:

```
[mapView setRegion:myRegion animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code it will help you:

```
- (void)location
{
    _locationManger =[[CLLocationManager alloc]init];
    _locationManger.distanceFilter=kCLDistanceFilterNone;
    _locationManger.desiredAccuracy=kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters;
    [_locationManger startUpdatingLocation];

    [map11 setMapType:MKMapTypeStandard];
    [map11 setZoomEnabled:YES];
    [map11 setScrollEnabled:YES];

    MKCoordinateRegion region={ {0.0,0.0 },{0.0,0.0}};

    region.center.latitude = 12.940358 ;
    region.center.longitude = 80.208647;
    region.span.longitudeDelta = 20.20f;
    region.span.latitudeDelta = 20.20f;

    [map11 setRegion:region animated:YES];
    [map11 setDelegate:sender];

}
```

It will show your desired location as

[image]

Comment: above code showing error use of undeclared identifier "Sender".if i comment that line its showing usual map page @Abhinandan Pratap

Comment: comment that line and call it in ViewDidLoad as [self location];

Answer (score 0):

first You have to  set  DELEGATE 
and Import  following in your .h file

```
    #import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
    #import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
```

after that make a property

```
@property(retain, nonatomic)  CLLocationManager *locationManager;
```

and in ViewDidLoad

```
mapview.delegate = self;
```

and then You can do like belew

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation
{
    MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(userLocation.coordinate, 800, 800);
    [self.mapView setRegion:[self.mapView regionThatFits:region] animated:YES];

    // Add an annotation
    MKPointAnnotation *point = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
        point.coordinate = userLocation.coordinate;
    point.title = @"Where am I?";
    point.subtitle = @"I'm here!!!";

    [self.mapView addAnnotation:point];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - to get User Current Location.
- (void)getUserLocation{
    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];


    self.locationManager.delegate = self;


#ifdef __IPHONE_8_0
    if([self getDeviceOSVersion].integerValue >= 8) {
        // Use one or the other, not both. Depending on what you put in info.plist
        [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
        [self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
    }
#endif
    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}
-(NSString *)getDeviceOSVersion{
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion];
}

#pragma mark - CLLocationManagerDelegate
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{
    UIAlertController *errorAlert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"ERROR" message:@"There was an error retrieving your location"preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert ];
    UIAlertAction* ok = [UIAlertAction
                         actionWithTitle:@"OK"
                         style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                         handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                         {
                             [errorAlert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

                         }];
    [errorAlert addAction:ok];
    [self presentViewController:errorAlert animated:YES completion:nil];
    NSLog(@"Error: %@",error.description);
}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations{
    CLLocation *currentLocation = [locations lastObject];
//currentLocation.coordinate.longitude =  currentLocation.coordinate.longitude ;
   // latitude =  currentLocation.coordinate.latitude;

      [self.locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];



}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code :

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D zoomLocation;
zoomLocation.latitude = 39.281516;
zoomLocation.longitude= -76.580806;

// 2
MKCoordinateRegion viewRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(zoomLocation, 0.5*METERS_PER_MILE, 0.5*METERS_PER_MILE);

// 3
[_mapView setRegion:viewRegion animated:YES];
```

This code will set your region in your map.. Then follow the steps to add annotation in your map..

```
// Add an annotation
MKPointAnnotation *point = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
point.coordinate = userLocation.coordinate; // Change coordinate as yours
point.title = @"Where am I?";
point.subtitle = @"I'm here!!!";

[self.mapView addAnnotation:point];
```

Hope it helps..

Answer (score 0):

add this code in your viewdidload

```
//self.locationManager replace it with your locationmgr 
     self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
        self.locationManager.delegate = self;
    #ifdef __IPHONE_8_0
        if(IS_OS_8_OR_LATER) {
            // Use one or the other, not both. Depending on what you put in info.plist
            [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
            [self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
        }
    #endif
        [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

        mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
        [mapView setMapType:MKMapTypeStandard];
        [mapView setZoomEnabled:YES];
        [mapView setScrollEnabled:YES];
```

in viewdidappear add below code

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:YES];

    self.locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    NSLog(@"%@", [self deviceLocation]);


    CLLocationCoordinate2D userLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake( self.locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude, self.locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude);
    MKPointAnnotation *annotation = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
    [annotation setCoordinate:userLocation];
    [annotation setTitle:@"Your Location"];
    [self.mapView addAnnotation:annotation];

    //always show the name of annotation
    [self.mapView selectAnnotation:annotation animated:YES];

    //location 1
    CLLocationCoordinate2D loc1Coord = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(18.998250, 72.848734);//add your latitude and longitude here
    MKPointAnnotation *annotation1 = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
    [annotation1 setCoordinate:loc1Coord];
    [annotation1 setTitle:@"title"];
    [annotation1 setSubtitle:@"subtitle"];
    [self.mapView addAnnotation:annotation1];

}
```

add this methods

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
        return nil;

    MKAnnotationView *annotationView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"loc"];
    annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;
    annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];

    return annotationView;
}
```

Thats it, you can see your latitude and longitude in the map.Let me know if it is working or not?

Comment: ya its working but not in zoomed and some error in if-else in viewdidload part for me @Madhu

Comment: can u post your viewdidload code and show me where you are getting error.